# node.js - include .js files within socket.on('connection') method

Tags: node.js, include, socket.io

Is it possible to include files like this? I need write a lot of code and it could help me with clarity.
P.S. Sorry for my English ;)

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
// include file1.js
// include file2.js
});
```

Content of file1.js

```
client.on('event1',function() {
// do something here...
});
```

Content of file2.js

```
client.on('event2',function() {
// do something here...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to conditionally load the JavaScript files, you could do something like this:

main.js

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
  setup1(client);
  setup2(client);
});
```

file1.js

```
function setup1(client) {
  client.on('event1',function() {
  // do something here...
  });
}
```

file2.js

```
function setup2(client) {
  client.on('event2',function() {
  // do something here...
  });
}
```

And of course you could make it all cleaner by using a library like [Postal.js](https://github.com/postaljs/postal.js) to handle inter-application communication.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)
btw: can I specify additional value for client? e.g. client.name=nickname?